# java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I'm currently retrieving data using XML-RPC, this is what I have:

```
Object[] params = new Object[]{param1, param2};
Object[] obj = new Object[]{};

try {
    obj = (Object[]) client.execute("method.name", params);
} catch (XmlRpcException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

return obj;
```

The problem is that sometimes it will return -1 and I'll get this error: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; - I was wondering if there was a way around this problem?

Comment: It looks like the return value of `client.execute` isn't actually an `Object[]`, but rather an `Integer`.

Comment: Or maybe an [`Object`](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/client/XmlRpcClient.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to check the type of the return value before casting.

```
Object result = client.execute(...);
if (result instanceof Integer) {
  Integer intResult = (Integer) result;
  ... handle int result
}    
else if (result instanceof Object[]) {
  obj = (Object[]) result;
}
else {
  ... something else
}
```

I'd be tempted to create a strongly-typed API around these RPC calls. But then again, maybe that's what you're already doing...